# Multithreaded zip file reading in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, zip

When I read zip file entries concurrently using multiple threads I get an InvalidData Exception telling me that the file header is corrupt. This doesn't happen when I read the file sequentially. My goal is to read through the entire zip file to check its integrity. I am trying to process each entry in the zip file in parallel to improve system utilisation and reduce the time it takes to complete.

Any suggestions on how to read zip file entries in parallel is greatly appreciated. Also, if there's a better way to test the integrity of a zip file or do high performance zip file reading in C# I'd love to know.

This code shows the problem (running on Windows 11):

```
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\testFolder");
foreach (var fInfo in dInfo.EnumerateFiles("*.zip", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{ // for each zip file in the folder
    ZipArchive zArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(fInfo.FullName);
    Parallel.ForEach(zArchive.Entries, zEntry =>
    { // for each entry in the zip file
        Stream entryStream = zEntry.Open(); // causes System.IO.InvalidDataException: 'A local file header is corrupt.'
        // ... test the zip integrity by reading its contents
    });
    zArchive.Dispose();
}
```

I assumed that by opening the zip file in read-only mode would allow multiple threads to read without affecting each other. Also, opening a stream for the zip entry doesn't have an option for setting a read-only mode.

I have tried moving the ZipFile.OpenRead into the parallel ForEach loop. This functions and is a lot faster than doing it sequentially for most of my test archives. Unfortunately it can be quite slow when there are a lot of small compressed files in a zip file. I assume this is due to lots of streams being opened and closed rapidly. It can be so slow that reading the zip file sequentially completes faster than reading in parallel.

Comment: Hi I think if you create the number of threads based on the number of files on each zip file then use each thread to extract only one file then you will achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ZipArchive` class would have to have been designed to be used from multiple threads, which it apparently was not. I'd think it unusual if it had been so designed.

You'd need to create multiple instances of `ZipArchive` for the same zip file, one for each entry, each in its own thread, as you have done. Then you should be able to process the zip file in parallel. Nothing keeps you from opening the same file for reading from multiple threads.

If you want to limit the overhead for small entries, then set a lower limit for the total uncompressed size you're willing to create a thread for. Have each thread process as many entries as needed to reach that lower limit.

Comment: I think winrar unzips files using multiple threads given it's speed. Now accessing that source code is story for another day because it's difficult.